# pandas does not read csv data with exponetial form

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a simple csv data file using pandas read_csv command. For some reason all values expressed in exponential form are converted to zeros.

Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong here and give me the instructions on how to do this correctly?

```
nlv12097@acv0105 TEST $ python
Job <886418> is submitted to queue <interq>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on apv0033>>
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print pd.__version__
0.7.3
>>> data = pd.read_csv('path_1_setup_sta_tta_MC30k.data', skiprows=[1])
>>> data.head()
                                               output name  mean  std.dev.  -sigma value  output value  +sigma value  output value.1
0              capture_path_clk_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/ck     0         0            -3             0             3               0
1  data_path_mult1/areg_reg_9/ck_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/d     0         0            -3             0             3               0
2          launch_clock_path_clk_delay_mult1/areg_reg_9/ck     0         0            -3             0             3               0
3                launch_path_clk_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/d     0         0            -3             0             3               0
4  stage_0001_delay_mult1/rc_cg_hier_inst5/rc_cgic_inst/ck     0         0            -3             0             3               0
>>> data.describe()
       mean  std.dev.  -sigma value  output value  +sigma value  output value.1
count   832       832           832           832           832             832
mean      0         0            -3             0             3               0
std       0         0             0             0             0               0
min       0         0            -3             0             3               0
25%       0         0            -3             0             3               0
50%       0         0            -3             0             3               0
75%       0         0            -3             0             3               0
max       0         0            -3             0             3               0
>>>
```

Including a sample data set:

```
nlv12097@acv0105 TEST $ head path_1_setup_sta_tta_MC30k.data
output name,mean,std.dev.,-sigma value,output value,+sigma value,output value

capture_path_clk_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/ck,2.240e-10,1.042e-11,-3.000,1.968e-10,3.000,2.607e-10
data_path_mult1/areg_reg_9/ck_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/d,1.074e-08,7.784e-11,-3.000,1.044e-08,3.000,1.097e-08
launch_clock_path_clk_delay_mult1/areg_reg_9/ck,2.438e-10,1.056e-11,-3.000,2.154e-10,3.000,2.816e-10
launch_path_clk_delay_mult1/out_reg_127/d,1.098e-08,7.860e-11,-3.000,1.068e-08,3.000,1.122e-08
stage_0001_delay_mult1/rc_cg_hier_inst5/rc_cgic_inst/ck,0.000e+00,0.000e+00,-3.000,0.000e+00,3.000,0.000e+00
stage_0001_slew_mult1/rc_cg_hier_inst5/rc_cgic_inst/ck,4.055e-12,2.390e-18,-3.000,4.055e-12,3.000,4.055e-12
stage_0002_delay_mult1/rc_cg_hier_inst5/rc_cgic_inst/q,2.438e-10,1.056e-11,-3.000,2.154e-10,3.000,2.816e-10
stage_0002_slew_mult1/rc_cg_hier_inst5/rc_cgic_inst/q,1.631e-10,4.559e-12,-3.000,1.498e-10,3.000,1.776e-10
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a display issue? That's it's just truncating the value in the display. so what does `data['mean'].iloc[0]` display?

Comment: All of the exponents are large negatives; maybe they're being rounded to 0?

Comment: Try using `pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2g}'.format)` to see if it is a display problem.

Comment: `data['mean'].iloc[0]` does not work `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iloc'`

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2g}'.format)` does not work either `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_option'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version is 0.7.3!? I can't even find documentation for that version anymore. Unless this version is absolutely critical to your system, please update it. That version has to be 7 years old or more. (Ok it's only 5 years old, but still.)

Alright. So I was able to find that version and do some testing. Given your sample set the view is as you say, but if you access an individual data point the numbers are as expected. For example:

```
df['mean'][0]
2.24e-10
```

My assumption is that internally somewhere, and we can't see the source so we have no idea where, there is a setting that says values this low are essentially 0. This is not the behavior in the current stable version of pandas (0.19.2). Again I strongly suggest upgrading.

Comment: Good to know that the data is still in there. `data['mean']` gives all zeros, but I will try multipyting series with 10e12, maybe the data will become visible.

Comment: This Enthought Python Distribution Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit) is installed on my company’s engineering environment. I will ask the IT department if it is possible upgrade to a more recent release.

Comment: @BorisL. I believe Enthought comes with a package manager by the name of `enpkg`. You could see if you have it installed by typing `which enpkg`, if it is there should be a path. Then you could update pandas with `enpkg pandas`

Comment: It is not possible for me to upgrade a package for the whole company. I could only download pandas 0.19 locally and somehow instruct Enthought to use that one instead, if that is possible at all…

Comment: @BorisL. I was under the impression you where working on a local system. If this is hosted on a network then I guess your out of luck, but if this is just on your desktop/laptop you should be able to upgrade.